# Understanding circular dependencies in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a sort of API. For that reason, there's the case where I try to import the main file (that exposes the API), which includes an export, of the file where the import call is coming from!

Confusing? Great!

Project structure:

```
/
/src
/src/js
/src/js/modules
/src/js/modules/moduleA/index|actions|components|selectors
/src/js/modules/moduleB/index|actions|components|selectors
/src/js/modules/moduleC/index|actions|components|selectors
```

See the example below where I expose a circular dependencies that doesn't work!

So, here's how a modular exposes the API (which works easily when exporting outside the module itself):

```
// src/modules/foobar/index.js
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as components from './components'
import * as containers from './containers'
import * as constants from './constants'
import reducer from './reducer'
import * as selectors from './selectors'
export default { actions, components, containers, constants, reducer, selectors }
```

Here's the import:

```
// src/modules/foobar/containers/index.js
import API from '../index.js'
// this is undefined
console.log('API', API)
```

The goal?

```
ModuleAPI.actions.foobar()
ModuleAPI.containers.foobar()
```

While I can see that it might be a bad practice (and honestly it seems common sense that a file can't import itself) I'd like to understand why this is not possible!

- just found a good read about this ( https://medium.com/content-uneditable/circular-dependencies-in-javascript-a-k-a-coding-is-not-a-rock-paper-scissors-game-9c2a9eccd4bc )
- may be worth researching https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin

Comment: What are you using for a module loader? Pretty sure the ES6 spec allows for circular dependencies no problem.

Comment: Webpack latest @CodingIntrigue

Comment: Have you tried your example in a real browser? Chrome, Firefox, Safari TP and Edge all support modules natively (some of them behind a flag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to import the top-level module like that. It just isn't possible to synchronously use it during the initialisation of the containers module. What happens is basically

```
load foobar/index.js
initialise foobar/index.js:
    load foobar/containers/index.js
    initialise foobar/containers/index.js:
        load foobar/index.js
        it's already getting initialised so don't wait
        set up scope
        execute module code: `API` is still undefined in the log statement
    finish initialisation of foobar/containers/index.js
    set up scope
    execute module code: `API` is getting defined now
finish initialisation of foobar/index.js
```

So as soon as you place the `console.log(API)` in a function and call it later, it'll work. Notice that with circular dependencies you need to take extra care that you always load the top level module first to get consistent evaluation order.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is more of a metaphilosophical problem: your module dependency actually turned into a cyclic graph, not a DAG/tree, so the module loading order cannot practically be dispatched by a topological sort, [and this is known as a very hard problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10608235/3289081).