How does EcmaScript handle recursive modules?
Recently I came across an eslint warning in my project about a circular dependency. I previously thought circular references are impossible in ES modules. But apparently they work in some situations.
I tried to reproduce the minimal working example of a circular dependency.
This works:
// ma.mjs
import { b } from "./mb.mjs";

export const a = 1;

export function fa() {
  console.log(b);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  fa();
});

// mb.mjs
import { a } from "./ma.mjs";

export const b = 2;

export function fb() {
  console.log(a);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  fb();
});

// script.mjs (entry point)
import './ma.mjs';

but the same code above without setTimeouts throws error, or to make it simpler, the code below does not work:
// ma.mjs
import { b } from "./mb.mjs";

export const a = 1;

console.log(b);

// mb.mjs
import { a } from "./ma.mjs";

export const b = 2;

console.log(a);

// script.mjs (entry point)
import './ma.mjs';

The error would be:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization

My questions are:

what criteria should there be for a circular reference to work? Why my first example works and the second one does not? Although they are both circularly dependent.
How does ES modules handle this recursive situation?

I've seen this explanation about recursive requires in NodeJS documentation, but not sure if that also applies to ES modules or not: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles . Does ES modules use the exact same mechanism as described here?

Which module are you loading as/from your entry point?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330595/1048572 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/46589957/1048572

THanks @Bergi, I added the entry point to my question content. The entry point is import ./ma.mjs

Just follow the code logic:
In the synchronous code, if you import ma.mjs, the first thing it does is import mb.mjs, which initialises b, then tries to print a, which is not set yet.
With timeouts, if you import ma.mjs, first it imports mb.mjs (same as before), it sets b, and puts a task to print a in the task queue. Then it continues executing ma.mjs, which sets a, and puts a task to print b in the task queue. This completes the initial task, and the queued tasks are fetched to run; but at this point, both a and b are defined, so there is no problem.
I.e. it might be better to look at this as a problem of timing, rather than a problem with circular imports. In effect, your examples are equivalent to:


console.log(a)                   // error
const a = 42



vs


setTimeout(() => console.log(a)) // no error
const a = 42



To analyse exactly what happens in the second snippet:

a is declared as a constant (declarations, but not initialisations, get hoisted to the top of the scope)
a printing task is scheduled, with a under closure
a is initialised
the scheduled printing task runs, and accesses the now-initialised a

In the first snippet, the printing itself is sandwiched between declaration and initialisation, where a does not yet have an explicitly set value.

Thanks. 2 questions: 1) You mentioned: "if you import ma.mjs the first thing it does is import mb.mjs, which initialises b", why isn't this just stuck in an infinite loop? Why when I import ma, which imports mb, does not again try to import ma, but instead initialises b?

for the timeout you mentioned: "it sets b, and puts a task to print a in the task queue", This part is not really about the timeout, but about the a being hidden in a function, right? Because if I instead do setTimeout(console.log.bind(this, a), 2) I will still get an error. Are functions what make circular possible?


@ArdeshirIzadi re 1): modules are handled as singletons. This solves a lot of issues, especially around circular dependencies. It's also simpler in other ways: consider module A which require B and C. But B also requires C. Activating A would then still only instantiate a single copy of C. Now consider some library the code uses extensively, like Lodash - a single copy is preferable. Interesting to note is that the singleton behaviour is not guaranteed per spec. However, in practice I've only seen singletons.

@ArdeshirIzadi re 2): what Amadan demonstrated and explained is correct. It's just hard to show the reverse. When the function  () => console.log(a) is created, it will capture the reference to a. But will not read it, thus won't cause a ReferenceError. However onsole.log.bind(this, a) will attempt to evaluate the reference to a. This will run afoul of the Temporal Dead Zone and thus produce a ReferenceError. There is no clear way to show the behaviour, though - if you try setTimeout(() => console.log(b)) it would fail but after the timeout runs.

Thanks. VLAZ. RIght. Its more clear now

Thanks @ Amadan. Your answer, plus @ VLAZ 's clarifications, plus following the links @ Bergi provided, made me kinda understand how this whole thing works.
